# Prove an equation using information about the derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, a differentiable twice function (meaning, the first and second derivative exist), such that: $f + f'' = 0$.
Show there are $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that: $f(x)=a\cdot cos(x) + b\cdot sin(x)$

I'd be glad for a direction and explanation about "How to figure it out" / "Way of thinking to get the solution".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=g(x)\sin x$, then
$$
f'=g'\sin x+g\cos x, \quad f''=g''\sin x +2g'\cos x-g\sin x. 
$$
and
$$
0=f''+f= g''(x)\sin x+2g'(x)\cos x.
$$
Thus
$$
0=g''(x)\sin^2 x+2g'(x)\sin x\cos x=\big(g'(x)\sin^2 x\big)',
$$
which implies that
$$
g'(x)\sin^2 x=c,
$$
and hence
$$
g'(x)=c\,\csc^2 x,
$$
which in turn implies that
$$
g(x)=-c\cot x+c',
$$
and finally that
$$
f(x)=c'\sin x-c\cos x.
$$

Comment: Can you explain how you got $g(x)$ from $g'(x)$ please?

Comment: it's juste a little 'mistake' it should be $-c \cot(x)+c'$

Answer (score 2):

That holds for any reals a and b. Second derivative of cos(x) is -cos(x) and second derivative of sin(x) is -sin(x) so f(x)+f''(x)=0 for any reals a and b.

Comment: Oh thanks, I just noticed I didn't get the question right. Cheers

Comment: You showed the inverse.